Custom functions with duckdb + dplyr in R
I love using Dplyr for cleaning/analyzing my datasets, but I'm working some big datasets which don't fit in my memory. So, I have modified my workflow to include DuckDB. The problem I'm facing now is how do I incorporate some of the custom functions I used with Dplyr into this workflow, for example lets look at this code:
con <- dbConnect(duckdb())

df <- tbl(con, "read_csv('xyz.csv')")
meta <- tbl(con, "read_json('meta.json')")

final <- left_join(
    df,
    meta |> 
      select(page_id, palign) |>
      mutate(page_id = str_glue("page_{page_id}")) |>
      rename(alignment = palign),
    by = "page_id",
  ) |>
  mutate(
    impressions = parse_bounds(impressions),
    spend = parse_bounds(spend),
  )

Here, I can't use str_glue which comes from the stringr package. I also can't use my parse_bounds function which converts a string like {'lower': '0', 'upper': '100'} and returns the mean of upper and lower bounds. I have also tried using duckplyr which converts the DuckDB table into a dataframe, so these transformations happen using R and not DuckDB which is very slow on my machine. I'm looking for solutions where I can have Dplyr's syntax but the processing happens in a faster backend such as DuckDb. What can I do here?

While I presume you would prefer to use your existing custom functions, I don't think this is currently possible: https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb-r/issues/181

I would suggest converting to base R / dplyr where possible. For instance, I expect mutate(page_id = paste0("page_", page_id)) should work.

If you want to have the benefits of DuckDB, you'll probably have to bite the bullet, at least to the extent of having most of the heavy lifting done on the DuckDB side.  There are likely to be many fringe benefits, especially as you're coming from R.
Specifically:
(1) Instead of str_glue(), use DuckDB's format function (see https://fmt.dev)
(2) DuckDB has numerous data types and it's easy enough to roll your own functions.  So for example, starting with DuckDB's structs:
create or replace function parse_bounds(s) as (
  s['lower']::FLOAT + s['upper']::FLOAT / 2
);

Usage:
select parse_bounds( {'lower': '0', 'upper': '100'} );
DuckDB also supports JSON, so you might want to consider that as a possibility as well.  Or perhaps go for polymorphism....
